# Termux: SSH connections fails

Tags: android, ssh, termux

I am trying to connect to a remote server via SSH from Termux on an Android 13 phone. That is the command:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/ssh-filename user@ip-address -p 12345
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning: Identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/ssh-filename not accessible: Not a directory. hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys_foreach failed for /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/known_hosts: Not a directory
```

Anything I can do to fix this issue? Is it a permission problem with Android 13?
No problems whatsoever on my 5 year old Android 9 phone.

Termux version: 0.118.0

Comment: You should check the directory and file permissions `ls - l /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/`

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that Termux is treating the provided paths as directories instead of files.

You can additionally:

1. Ensure that your SSH private key (ssh-filename) and the `known_hosts` file are placed in the correct directory.
2. Make sure that the paths to your SSH key and known hosts files are correctly specified in your SSH command.
3. Check if the file permissions for your SSH key file are set correctly.